# Passing values to a controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am struggling with passing all the data I need to a controller in MVC. The code is as follows:

```
 <td><a href=@Url.Action("AddCourseToStudentPlan", "Users", new { 
courseID = c.CourseId, userID = user.UserId, semNum = num}) title="Add Course 
to Semester" >"Here"</a></td>
```

(currently num is defined as `var num = 1;`, which of course won't work.)

The course ID's and userID's are passing fine. these values are coming from a `ViewBag` essentially.

However, semNum is dependent on something entirely different:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="Semtabs">
                    @{ var year = plan.CatalogYear; }
                    <li class="active"><a href="#SEM1" onclick="StoreNum(1)" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Fall @year</a></li>
                    @{ year += 1; }
                    <li class=""><a href="#SEM2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Spring @year</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#SEM3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Fall 2014</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#SEM4" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Spring 2015</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#SEM5" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Fall 2015</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#SEM6" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Spring 2016</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#SEM7" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Fall 2016</a></li>
                    ...
```

The intended output is that when the user clicks on one of the tabs, they see a list of courses that they have added, and are able to add courses to this tab by clicking on the link in the code previous code block. Therefore, clicking on a tab should change the value of `num` in the `@Url.Action()` method. But of course I can't do this because C# is server side.

So the problem is, how am I able to pass some variable semNum (which is determined client-side) to the `@Url.Action()` method after the page loads?

Comment: You can post the final `num` value to your server when the user clicks the link, and redirect to that action accordingly in your Controller

Comment: your question is not really clear to me. But on anyway if your problem is with the Url.Action, then you can skip using it. Just use a java script function, in the function do what ever you need to figure out the number and do the redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. This one is fairly intuitive and will not cause syntax errors in Visual Studio.

1. Create a URL template with the info you know.
2. When the link is clicked, look at the current state of the tabs.
3. Use that information to complete the URL.
4. Navigate as desired.

```html
<!-- define a link/button, but don't set the URL -->
<a id="add-url-button">Add Course to Semester</a>

<!-- your existing tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="Semtabs">
    <li><a href="#SEM2" data-semester-number="2">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#SEM3" data-semester-number="3">Tab 2</a></li>

    <!-- etc. -->
</ul>
```

```js
<script>

// Create a URL template    

// It sounds like semNum is the only value that needs to vary,
// but you can create a template with multiple placeholders.

// We pass zero for semNum so that routes will still match without
// conflicting with a real semester number.
var addUrlTemplate = '@Url.Action("AddCourseToStudentPlan", "Users", new { courseID = c.CourseId, userID = user.UserId, semNum = 0 }';

// jQuery here for brevity (will work fine with vanilla JS)

var addButton = $("#add-url-button"),
    tabs = $("#Semtabs");

addButton.click(function(){

    // determine the selected tab by interrogating the list of tabs
    var activeTab = tabs.find("li.active"),
        semesterNumber = activeTab.attr("semester-numer");

    // Construct the complete URL. Depending on the URL, you may need
    // a smarter regex. Be sure that there is no chance of accidentally
    // replacing the wrong value.
    var addUrl = addUrlTemplate.replace(/0$/, semesterNumber);

    // navigate as desired
    window.location.href = addUrl;
));

</script>
```

Comment: I should have been more clear, but I wrote this up very quickly; apologies. The courseID is also variable, as I would like the user to be able to select that as well. So setting a premade url this way wouldn't work. However, I think I might be able to modify this solution so that a javascript function builds the correct URL. Much thanks!